# Gitlab Runner registration failing on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssl, ssl-certificate, centos7, gitlab

After searching a lot on the Internet about the problem that I'm having when I try to register the gitlab runner, I was able to verify that the problem was related to SSL certificates. I've looked for solutions to the problem and came across these two "solutions":

["Solution 1"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/267#note_2668095)

["Solution 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458410/gitlab-ci-runner-ignore-self-signed-certificate)

Before I tried to apply these "solutions", the error that appeared after the runner's registration attempt was this:

**Previous ERROR:**

[image: Previous ERROR]

And after I tried to apply the two procedures above, the error that now appears is this:

**Current ERROR:**

[image: Current ERROR]

I have no idea what these IP SANs are or how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance to anyone who can take a little time to help me with this problem.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622879/cannot-validate-certificate-for-ip-address-because-it-doesnt-contain-any-ip-s.

Comment: THX. I'm going to check it out